# How to convert this XML in RotateAnimation() format with float values in java?

Tags: android, animation

```
<rotate
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

I want to pass degrees dynamically, hence thinking of RotateAnimation(). But unable to convert all arguments to float as required by RotateAnimation constructor.

Comment: so what argument are you unable to convert?

Comment: I want to pass toDegrees argument as a dynamic value.

Comment: so use `RotateAnimation` constructor that takes `toDegrees` parameter

Comment: @Neha please check my answer.

Comment: I have tried this code, it's working. but I want to pass -30f value as a parameter.   rotation= new rotateAnimation(-90f,-30f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f);
  
                rotation.setDuration(5000);

                rotation.setFillAfter(true);
                two.startAnimation(rotation);

Comment: and if its working, whats your problem with `-30f` then?

Comment: -30f is static value. i want to pass the variable. 
However I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use rotate animation on your regular ImageView like so.

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
 matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivotX, pivotY);
 imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Mahesh, i want to rotate an image dynamically. I don't want XML involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
int i=seekbar.getProgress();
i=i-90;
float **newFloat** = (float) i;
rotation= new RotateAnimation(-90f,**newFloat**,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f);

rotation.setDuration(5000);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
two.startAnimation(rotation); //two is an imageview
```